# Can't switch between tabs having ToolTipText assigned (JTabbedPane)

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jlabel, jtabbedpane

I have a JFrame extended class that implements a multi-tab chat. Every tab is a chat with someone or with a group of people. What I have implemented works fine, except when I assign a ToolTipText to the label of a tab. In this case I can't click anymore (and select) the tab that has a ToolTipText assigned. The others work fine.

Graphical example:
[image]

As you can see the tabs are properly being added, and the first two tabs ("Gruppo prova" and "Gruppo test") have a ToolTipText, the other two don't. I can switch between the last two, but I can't do the same with the first two. I thought that the icon next to the label could be a problem, but I removed it and still doesn't work. However I can still click all the 'X' (close) buttons (working properly).

This is a piece of the code I used to add a tab:

```
        // Some stuff...
        JChat chat = new JChat(gui.chatClient, email, name, group);
        jTabbedPane.add(email, chat); // I instantiated this before

        int index = jTabbedPane.indexOfTab(email);
        JPanel pnlTab = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        pnlTab.setOpaque(false);

        // Core function
        JLabel lblTitle;

        if (group == 1) {
        // If it's a group and not a single chat I assign a name, an icon and a ToolTipText to the tab
            lblTitle = new JLabel(name, icon, JLabel.LEFT);
            lblTitle.setToolTipText(membersList.toString());
        } else {
        // otherwise I only assign a name to the tab
            lblTitle = new JLabel(name);
        }

        jTabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(index, pnlTab);

        // This applies the 'X' (close) button next to the tab name
        CloseButton btnClose = new CloseButton(this, jTabbedPane, tabs, email);

        lblTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 5));

        pnlTab.add(lblTitle);
        pnlTab.add(btnClose);
```

Is this a Swing bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use :

1. [`void setToolTipTextAt(int, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setToolTipTextAt%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) to set tool-tip text to specific tab.
2. [`void setIconAt(int index, Icon icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setIconAt%28int,%20javax.swing.Icon%29) to set the icon to specific tab.

No need to use `JLabel` for setting `tool-tip text` or `icon`.

**The above solution, however doesn't however answer your question:**

> except when I assign a ToolTipText to the label of a tab. In this
>   case I can't click anymore (and select) the tab that has a ToolTipText
>   assigned

**The only reason i am suspecting:**

`JLabel` doesn't register to any mouse listener by default. When no mouse listener is set to `JLabel` any mouse clicked event will go through to the  UI objects underneath: in this case the `JTabbedPane`. But when we are setting tool-tip text using `setToolTipText(text)`, the `ToolTipManger` adds a mouse listener to this `JLabel`, which will continue to consume the mouse click event.

Check the following code snippets demonstrating the issue and providing a work around `setSelectedIndex` function:

```
    JLabel label = new  JLabel("a Label");
    System.out.println(label.getMouseListeners().length); // length is printed as 0

    label.setToolTipText("Danger: setting tool tip will consume mouse event");
    System.out.println(label.getMouseListeners().length); // length is printed as 1

    jTabbedPane1.setTabComponentAt(0, label);

    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           int index =  jTabbedPane1.indexOfTabComponent((Component)e.getSource());
           jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(index);
        }

    });
```

Comment: @PierpaoloBagnasco, not likely a bug, but component design issue. Check the updated answer

Comment: Very good job, thanks for the explanation and the depth study!